# After page refresh using setTimeout, display tab that was being displayed before page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery tabs, and on one of my tabs there is function that refreshs the page and then displays that same tab after the refresh.

Here is what I have so far, but it does not seem to set the tab to active:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    location.reload();
    $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1});
}, 1000);
```

My tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id ="tabList" style="line-height: 3.3;">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Carrier Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
    <%--This is Carrier Details Tab--%>   
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <%@include file="carrierProfileDetails.jspf" %>
    </div>
    <%--This is Contacts Tab--%>  
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <%@include file="carrierProfileContacts.jspf" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the contacts tab to be displayed after the refresh.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should just put `$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1});` at the top of your js. `.reload()` refreshes the webpage and wipes out your js state, so no lines below it will ever run.

Comment: `location.reload()` is the same as hitting F5.  As such, any logic that you try to perform after doing so is going to be erased when the page reloads.

Comment: @wassona so is it possible to get what I want then?

Comment: My suggestion would make it so the page focuses on the tab every time it's loaded, whether it was refreshed due to that function or not. If you need the exact functionality you defined, you should look into `localStorage`. I don't know a lot about it, but it should be able to solve that issue (possibly with spotty browser support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for your case, you can set/get/update data and it will be accessible after refresh. Here  is a simple example, but it will not work in snippet, you can create HTML page locally and check it out (it works fine locally):

```html
<body>
  <h1>Active tab: <span id="tab-number"></span></h1>

  <button onclick="changeTab('1')">Tab 1</button>
  <button onclick="changeTab('2')">Tab 2</button>
  <button onclick="changeTab('3')">Tab 3</button>

  <script>
      var ssActiveTab = sessionStorage.getItem('activeTab');
      if (ssActiveTab) {
          changeTab(ssActiveTab);
      }
      function changeTab(newTab) {
          document.getElementById('tab-number').innerText = newTab;
          sessionStorage.setItem('activeTab', newTab);
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

The main idea is to set current state of tabs to `sessionStorage` on every change and get the last state from it on page load. If item exists and has a value - then set the state based in this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.reload();
```

This will reload the webpage and not a single line after this will be executed.

If you want to always activate the same tab on page load, write `$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1});` on `body onload` method.